# Compass in Sympfony in dev but not in production

Tags: ruby, symfony, sass, assetic

I'm on a Symfony2 project with Compass and Sass included. I don't want Compass/Ruby/Sass to be required on the production server; only in development. Is that possible?

I actually use this in the templates:

```
{% stylesheets filter="compass" output="css/style.css"
  "@myLandingPageBundle/Resources/assets/sass/style.scss" %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

config.yml :

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        ['myLandingPageBundle']
    ruby: %ruby.bin%
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass:
            bin: %sass.bin%
        compass:
            bin: %compass.bin%
```

**Dev** : Css are generated dynamically and not physically.

**Prod** : I use `./app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug` to generate assets and CSS from Sass files only when there are changes. That means that I use Compass in production.; I don't want that because the server will not necessary have Ruby installed.

Comment: Do you have something like capistrano for your deployment? Or how is your deployment organized?

Comment: You could dump all of your assets before you upload/commit/etc and then not run that when you deploy.

Comment: @23tux Yes I have Webistrano https://github.com/peritor/webistrano !

Comment: @Qoop If I use assetic:dump before, I have to commit my generated assets so they can be on the prod server with the deployment ?

Comment: Yeah, you would need to dump and commit every time you make a change to any of your assets.

Comment: @Qoop Thanks for the precisions ! I think it would be better if I only commit the generated css and not all my assets. If I don't configure compass/sass in config.yml but in config_dev.yml, then when I run assetic:dump of my prod environment, there is no sass compilation and it's my committed css which will be used ! Do you think it is correct ? 
Thank a lot for helping me to improve my thinking on this !